# Teradata TXT File Import via VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, teradata

I have a text file(~300,000 records) that is created via multiple combined reports(some from an OBDC connection to Teradata and some not). I need to import that file into Teradata.  I know I can use TD Studio Express but since the report is generated in Excel, I would rather not have to open another program.

I cant find any documentation on how to import a TXT file via VBA into Teradata.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the Teradata Parallel Transporter?

Comment: Trying to do that via ODBC/VBA will be painfully slow, I think.  As @Nathan_Sav said, look into TPT, MLoad, etc.